# VBA concatenated arrays comparison - error 1004 coming up

Tags: excel, vba

I have these entries in rows 1 to 10 and columns A to D:

```
a   10  a   10
b   20  b   20
c   30  c   30
d   40  d   40
e   50  e   50
f   60  f   60
g   70      
h   80      
i   90      
j   100
```

With VBA code (that I will paste below), I am wanting to, using VBA arrays, build a concatenated "virtual column" of A and B and C and D. Then, I am wanting to create a third array that is populated with an array that gives me a MATCH result for each array element using the concatenation of A and B compared to the same of C and D. (There's a point to all this: it's the prototype of something more complex I want to build later on.)

It works up until the 6th element in the array, but beyond that it gives me the 1004 error (with element values after that Empty in the Watch window).

Can anyone give me some pointers why?

Here is the (probably inelegant) VBA code:

```
Sub concatarray()

Dim count1 As Integer
Dim count2 As Integer
count1 = Application.CountA(Columns("A:A"))
count2 = Application.CountA(Columns("C:C"))
Dim Column1() As Variant
Dim Column2() As Variant
Dim virtColumn3() As Variant
Dim Column4() As Variant
Dim Column5() As Variant
Dim virtColumn6() As Variant
ReDim virtColumn3(1 To count1, 1 To 1)
ReDim virtColumn6(1 To count2, 1 To 1)
Column1 = Range("A1:A" & count1)
Column2 = Range("B1:B" & count1)
Column4 = Range("E1:E" & count2)
Column5 = Range("F1:F" & count2)
For i = 1 To count1 
    virtColumn3(i, 1) = Column1(i, 1) & Column2(i, 1)
Next i
For i = 1 To count2
    virtColumn6(i, 1) = Column4(i, 1) & Column5(i, 1)
Next i
Dim virtColumn7() As Variant
ReDim virtColumn7(1 To count1, 1 To 1)
For i = 1 To count1
    virtColumn7(i, 1) = WorksheetFunction.Match(virtColumn3(i, 1), virtColumn6, 0)
Next i

End Sub
```

It's almost definitely this snippet that's wrong:

```
 For i = 1 To count1
        virtColumn7(i, 1) = WorksheetFunction.Match(virtColumn3(i, 1), virtColumn6, 0)
 Next i
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`WorksheetFunction.Match()` throws an error if a match is not found.

Instead of trapping that error, you can use the `Application.Match()` version, which *returns* an error:

```
Dim v 'variant  
For i = 1 To count1
    v = Application.Match(virtColumn3(i, 1), virtColumn6, 0)
    If Not IsError(v) Then virtColumn7(i, 1) = v
Next i
```

Comment: Thanks Tim - I'll try yours in a while and report back. I wasn't aware that there was a difference between WorksheetFunction.<Function> and Application.<Function>.

Comment: All good - thanks for the answer. I'll explore the difference between using WorksheetFunction and Application now.

Answer (score 1):

It crashes because the `Match` function doesn't find the item.

You could use `On Error Resume Next` and then check the value of `Err` to see if the match was found.

Also, you don't need to `Dim Column1() As Variant`. A variant can be an array, so `Dim Column1 As Variant` it's cleaner.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, stenci. I'll give it a go and see if I can figure it out.